# is it possible to display the size of the circles according to a factor variable with leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to create a map with the leaflet package in R.

[image]

I would like the size of the points to depend on a categorical variable.
this variable contains 3 classes: [1-5], [5-10] and [ 10-15]. So I wish there were 3 sizes
here is the code that allowed me to make this map :

```
leaflet(geo)%>% addTiles() %>% addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>% addGeoJSON(geojson, weight = 2, color = "#000000", fill = FALSE) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(~LONGITUDE, ~LATITUDE, weight = 4,radius = ~0.25, opacity = 0.9, color = ~pal1(NETWORK_TYPE_FOR_PERIOD)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = pal1, values = ~sort(NETWORK_TYPE_FOR_PERIOD), opacity = 0.8, title = c(""),
            position = "bottomright")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a grouping variable to the data set:

```
geo %>% mutate(grouping_var = case_when(
     `your character variable` == "character value"~ 50,
     `your character variable`== "character value"~ 100),
     grouping_var = as.numeric(grouping_var ))
```

and then just change the radius from radius = ~.25 to geo$grouping_var